# Convert months mmm to numeric

Tags: r, datetime

I have been given a csv with a column called month as a char variable with the first three letters of the month. E.g.:

```
"Jan", "Feb","Mar",..."Dec"
```

Is there any way to convert this to a numeric representation of the month, 1 to 12, or even a type that is in a date format?

Comment: Extra credit: give an answer that works if your month abbreviations are not in English! (e.g. "Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Avr", "Mai",  ...) [Hint: you can probably do this by temporarily switching your system locale and using `as.Date` with the `%b` format ...]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use `match` and the predefined vector `month.abb`:

```
tst <- c("Jan","Mar","Dec")
match(tst,month.abb)
[1]  1  3 12
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use the built-in vector `month.abb` to check against when converting to a number, eg :

```
mm <- c("Jan","Dec","jan","Mar","Apr")

sapply(mm,function(x) grep(paste("(?i)",x,sep=""),month.abb))
Jan Dec jan Mar Apr 
  1  12   1   3   4
```

The grep construct takes care of differences in capitalization. If that's not needed,

```
match(mm,month.abb)
```

works just as fine.

If you also have a day and a year column, you can use any of the conversion functions, using the appropriate codes (see also `?strftime`)

eg

```
mm <- c("Jan","Dec","jan","Mar","Apr")
year <- c(1998,1998,1999,1999,1999)
day <- c(4,10,3,16,25)

dates <- paste(year,mm,day,sep="-")

strptime(dates,format="%Y-%b-%d")
[1] "1998-01-04" "1998-12-10" "1999-01-03" "1999-03-16" "1999-04-25"
```

Comment: Thanks Joris, this is also useful. I will have to paste the column to get an actual date for a time series with it.

Answer (score 6):

Just adding to the existing answers and the comment in the question:

```
readr::parse_date("20/DEZEMBRO/18","%d/%B/%y",locale=locale("pt"))
```

Results date format `"2018-12-20"`. `locale("pt")` is for Portuguese, which is used in Brazil, can do `"es"` for Spanish, `"fr"` for French etc.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options using:

```
vec <- c("Jan","Dec","Jan","Apr")
```

are

```
> Months <- 1:12
> names(Months) <- month.abb
> unname(Months[vec])
[1]  1 12  1  4
```

and/or

```
> match(vec, month.abb)
[1]  1 12  1  4
```